# Spring JMS CachingConnectionFactory doesn't seem to reconnect on exception

Tags: spring, exception, jms, reconnect

The JMS connection didn't get reconnected when this exception happened:

```
2014-08-16 10:51:36,724 WARN  [TIBCO EMS TCPLink Reader (Server-12486338)] connection.CachingConnectionFactory - Encountered a JMSException -    resetting the underlying JMS Connection
javax.jms.JMSException: Connection has been terminated
    at com.tibco.tibjms.Tibjmsx.buildException(Tibjmsx.java:502)
    at com.tibco.tibjms.TibjmsConnection._onDisconnected(TibjmsConnection.java:2286)
    at com.tibco.tibjms.TibjmsConnection$ServerLinkEventHandler.onEventDisconnected(TibjmsConnection.java:341)
    at com.tibco.tibjms.TibjmsxLinkTcp$LinkReader.work(TibjmsxLinkTcp.java:320)
    at com.tibco.tibjms.TibjmsxLinkTcp$LinkReader.run(TibjmsxLinkTcp.java:247)
2014-08-16 10:51:40,286 WARN  [TIBCO EMS TCPLink Reader (Server-12494013)] connection.CachingConnectionFactory - Encountered a JMSException - resetting the underlying JMS Connection
javax.jms.JMSException: Connection has been terminated
    at com.tibco.tibjms.Tibjmsx.buildException(Tibjmsx.java:502)
    at com.tibco.tibjms.TibjmsConnection._onDisconnected(TibjmsConnection.java:2286)
    at com.tibco.tibjms.TibjmsConnection$ServerLinkEventHandler.onEventDisconnected(TibjmsConnection.java:341)
    at com.tibco.tibjms.TibjmsxLinkTcp$LinkReader.work(TibjmsxLinkTcp.java:320)
    at com.tibco.tibjms.TibjmsxLinkTcp$LinkReader.run(TibjmsxLinkTcp.java:247)
```

The exact same error happened a few seconds apart and I wonder if Spring tried to reconnect and gave up after two tries.

I checked Spring source code and didn't find reconnection logic in onException() method in either CachingConnectionFactory or its parent class SingleConnectionFactory.  We're using spring-jms 3.1.2 but I looked at the latest Spring source code as well.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I only see tibco classes in your stacktrace. If you're not using the `JmsTemplate` or a listener container such as `DefaultMessageListenerContainer` you're looking at the wrong place. Show some config maybe?

Comment: I was wondering about the same thing too.  Here's the config:

Comment: Just figured out we're using the Tibco connection factory directly.  Thanks for the tip.

Comment: how did you resolve the issue? I am seeing the same error with tibco `javax.jms.JMSException: Connection has been terminated`

Comment: it's also can be a problem on TIbco EMS side http://www.techieswiki.com/how-to-enable-automatic-re-connection-to-ems-after-a-network-outage-or-ems-restart.html

Answer (score 2):

I had similar issue where DefaultMessageListenerContainer  is unable to reconnect once an exception happens(when TIBCO primary server stops and switch over to secondary TIBCO server).

I was using SingleConnectionFactory and it was causing the issue.

Fetching the connectionFactory directly from Websphere using java:comp/env/jms/TIBCOConnectionFactory resolved this issue.